# Making New Categories with Cut-points for a continuous Dependent Variable in a repeated measure Study

Tags: repeated-measures, data-transformation, multilevel-analysis, continuous-data

In one study with repeated measures design, the volume of cutaneous masses has been calculated for each subject (based on the measurement of the length, width, and height of the mass by the caliper) on three time occasions at specified intervals. This study aimed to investigate volume changes over time in each subject and compare the model of these changes between different treatment and control groups. Now we want to examine the outcomes associated with the dependent variable, namely volume, in three new categories as follows:
-Volume reduction less than 80% of the baseline value(ineffective)
-Volume reduction equal to or greater than 80% of the baseline value(effective)
-Spontaneous rupture(bad news-ineffective)
The questions are:
1)How and with which menu commands in the SPSS software program can the volume variable be categorized? (Especially for the third category )
2)Would data analysis by two-level mixed-effects modeling be appropriate given the above categorization? If not, what method (s) do you suggest?

Continued,...

New information:

Data structure includes treatment A (n=67), treatment B (n=71), positive control or placebo groups for A and B, each n=17 (totally n= 34) and a negative control group(n=28) ,So the total number is N=200.
The number of cases leading to rupture recorded in each of the above groups is as follows: Treatment A (n=1) Treatment B (n=2) Placebo A(n=8) Placebo B (n=10) and the negative Control group (n=0).
Level-2 fixed explanatory variables recorded for each subject are animal species, breed, sex, age, and body condition score. Volume data is complete for time-points 0, 1, and 2, but for time-point 3 it is only available for 16 subjects from the placebo groups, which does not seem to be sufficient and It may be better to remove it from the dataset at all….,
But the questions:

1)With these in mind, what analytical approach should be considered for placebo groups(3 and 4)?
2)If I understand Properly, to have 2-level modeling of volume change in this data set, should modeling for each of the above five groups be done separately for each group, first without a predictor and in later steps by adding predictors and explanatory variables of level-1 and level-2 to the model and then adding interactions to explain potential variability in the slopes between groups?

Answer (score 0):

First, as comments and an answer on [your previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/527203/28500) indicated, you need to have a separate indicator outcome variable for the cases that ruptured spontaneously. I don't know of a way for *any* statistical software* to infer whether a drop to zero volume came from an effective volume-reduction treatment versus spontaneous rupture. You will need to do that yourself.

Second, before you break your volume changes into rupture, effective, and ineffective as 3 separate categorical outcomes, make sure that there is a clean distinction between those last 2 categories based on your 80% cutoff. If so, then the simplest solution is to see--for non-rupture cases--whether the final volume is less than 20% of initial volume, and mark those as "effective" responses. Other non-rupture cases would be "ineffective." (I assume that the first measurement is pre-treatment, second and third during/after treatment if any.) That gives each case a single rupture/ineffective/effective outcome. It discards results from the second measurement on each individual, however.

If that outcome categorization is warranted, then there is no repeated measure requiring mixed modeling. Each individual will have a *single* outcome measure: rupture/ineffective/effective. A simple multinomial regression is all that would be required.

If there isn't a clear distinction between effective/ineffective volume changes in non-rupture cases, however, then that outcome categorization might not be a good idea (even though it's what I recommended in an [answer to your previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/529625/28500)). You might then be better served by jointly modeling both the binary rupture/not outcome and continuous volume changes for the non-ruptured cases. It's hard to say what's best, without seeing examples of the data.

---

*Software-specific questions, e.g. about SPSS, are off-topic here.